# Multiple recipient mail php not working for second onwards addresses

Tags: php

I have an HTML email needed to be sent to more than one person:

```
$mem = "abc@def.com, qwr@rty.com";
$subject = 'Invitation to Party';
$headers = "From: info@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: info@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "SNIPPED";
mail($mem, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

It is sending to the first email which is `abc@def.com`, but it's not sending mail for the second recipient which is `qwr@rty.com` and the rest.

The email addresses are examples.

Is there any work-around for this besides using library?

Comment: verify that the second email id is a exising one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may send the second id as a bcc,

```
  $headers .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";
```